# Pronunciation of 's after word ending in "is", "es"

Tags: pronunciation, possessives, apostrophe

Alexis's sister. Is it pronounced Alec **sis sis**ter or Ale**c sis sis sis**ter?

Comment: Both pronunciations are acceptable.

Comment: Both are okay, I prefer the second though.

Comment: I agree with the second, without it "Alex sis sis" from the example the speaker sounds to my ear like they don't know English that well.  Especially remembering that the apostrophe is a placeholder or shorthand for a missing letter or two.

Comment: Imagine you had to distinguish the sisters of Alec, Alex, Alice, and Alexis. Would those all sound different from each other as possessives? Should they?

Comment: I "pronounce" it as "sister of Alexis." Problem solved!

Comment: Using your nomenclature, I would pronounce it **Alec sis is sister**. (But that's a very subtle distinction. In the main, I use the second version.)